# Remove <figure> tag on my RSS Feed

Tags: functions, customization, tags, rss, feed

I need to remove the  tag that appears on my feed content ($content variable).

http://mkt-d.hospedagemdesites.ws/wp/feed/

Is there an existing function to this task?

Some  tags appear with width instructions that are differents on each appear. How can I remove them completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most direct way of customizing WordPress feeds is to hook into them directly with the following filter.
Edit: as we talked about, let's just edit the content to tear out any

```
function edit_your_feed_content($content) {
    $content = preg_replace("/(<figure.*?[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/figure>)/i", "", $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'edit_your_feed_content');
```

Comment: Hi, Chris. Thanks! Whats the syntax to remove every figure item?

Comment: It will remove figure tag for all new posts or it will work on older posts too? Again, thanks!

Comment: It should work on new and old. You are filtering the content that gets pushed back to your RSS Feed.

Comment: I added the function but it won't work. http://mkt-d.hospedagemdesites.ws/wp/feed/ figure items are still showing. Any suggestion? And thanks again. I'm really thankful you're giving attention to this post.

Comment: I just updated the block above, give that a try! This time we are also going to filter `the_content` and see if that can't resolve it.

Comment: Hi, Chris! I paste this code on functions.php in theme folder, didnt work. On wp-includes/ folder, it didnt work too. Any suggestion?

Comment: Victor, I tried the snippet on my end before I sent it over and it's working as we hoped. Maybe you have a plugin that has it's hand in that feed, or something else built that is compiling this feed? I am at a loss right now....sorry :(

Comment: Hi, Chris. What if I wanted to wipe out that <figure> tag from posts instead of feed? Would it work?

Comment: Sure!! You can take out the `if(is_feed()) {` statement surrounding that preg_replace and that should do it! If you are wanting to edit just the content, I'd also remove the `add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'edit_your_feed_content');
` portion of it. Hope that helps!!

Comment: I tried to do it this way: add_filter('the_content', function( $content ){
    //remove os figure-
        $content = preg_replace("/(<figure.*?[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/figure>)/i", "", $content);
        return $content;
}

But I'm getting this error: "unexpected T_Function". I believe its because my PHP version is under 5.3. (its 5.2). You have any idea how I could do this the "older way"?

Comment: So anonymous function support wasn't available until 5.3. You can't pass a function as a parameter in the `add_filter()`. I'll edit the answer to get that looking right for you....