# Remove <figure> HTML tags from all posts

Tags: posts, functions, html

How can I remove  tags from all posts on WordPress?

I want to remove that  tag from my WP feed: mkt-d.hospedagemdesites.ws/wp/feed. I'm using that feed to output posts in an external blog and the  tag is disturbing it.

I'm using PHP 5.2.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the community. In order to help you better, I'd like to understand better your requirement and what have you attempted so far or the intended goal. Removing `<figure>` tags  would delete all the insertion of the images in the posts, so I'd like to understand why you would want to do that, in order to help you with an accurate answer.

Comment: Hi Jesus! Thank you! I want to remove that <figure> tag from my WP feed: http://mkt-d.hospedagemdesites.ws/wp/feed/. I'm using that feed to output posts in an external blog and the <figure> tag is disturbing it. Note that right after the <figure> tags, there is an <img> tag. Would that image disappear too? How do you suggest I do it?

Comment: Well, the figure tag actually can help your SEO, because it associates in the `figcaption` tag, a description for the image inside it. While you think of it "disturbing", the search engines find it very useful, and browsers too.

Comment: Also, you have edited your question making it even broader, too much I'd say, because there could exists legitimate and useful cases where you need to remove a tag (think for example, Accelerated Mobile Pages), but it would help you to receive a useful answer, if you specify (in your question), if you only want to remove it from the feed (and not from the original site), and if you have access to the original site or only to the code you are using to repost in the external blog (and that sounds worrysome for SEO because of duplicated content).

Comment: Jesus, I'm not displaying content on the external blog, just a link to original blog and some excerpt.

Comment: You already received an answer to this yesterday: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339783/remove-figure-tag-on-my-rss-feed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove <figure> tag on my RSS Feed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339783/remove-figure-tag-on-my-rss-feed)